# No module name "foo"

Tags: python

I'm trying to import file from parent directory, and so far have no luck:

```
.
├── e.py
├── __init__.py
├── q.py
└── subproject
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── sfile.py
```

Here is the code for `sfile.py`

```
 import sys, os                                                                  

 topdir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]),   
                                                 os.pardir, os.pardir))          
 if os.path.exists(os.path.join(topdir, "project", "__init__.py")):        
     sys.path.insert(0, topdir)                                         

 from project import e
```

And it is giving me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sfile.py", line 8, in <module>
    from project import e
ImportError: No module named project
```

But if I go to the python interpreter and do the same, it works:

```
>>> import os, sys
>>> topdir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]), os.pardir, os.pardir))
>>> if os.path.exists(os.path.join(topdir, "project", "__init__.py")):
...     sys.path.insert(0, topdir)
... 
>>> from project import e
IN e
>>>
```

And here is my `e.py` file:

```
print "IN e"
```

## EDIT:

```
sergey@sergey-PC:~/tmp/project/subproject$ ls
__init__.py  __init__.pyc  sfile.py  sfile.pyc  www.py  www.pyc
sergey@sergey-PC:~/tmp/project/subproject$ pwd
/home/sergey/tmp/project/subproject
sergey@sergey-PC:~/tmp/project/subproject$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:13:16) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
'/home/sergey/tmp/project/subproject'
>>>
```

Here is the output when trying to do `from .. import e`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sfile.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import e
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

For `sys.argv[0]`:
in interpreter:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv[0]
''
>>>
```

when adding `print sys.argv[0]` at the top of the file:

```
sergey@sergey-PC:~/tmp/project/subproject$ python sfile.py
sfile.py
```

#### UPDATE on `sys.argv[0]`

```
sergey@sergey-PC:~/tmp/project/subproject$ python sfile.py
/home/sergey/tmp/project/subproject/sfile.py
```

interpeter:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
'/home/sergey/tmp/project/subproject'
>>>
```

Comment: When I saw the title, I thought you were actually naming a module "foo". I died a little bit.

Comment: What's your working directory when you run sfile.py vs when you run python directly?

Comment: Did you try `print topdir` in the two different contexts to see the difference? I get `/` in the python interpreter, no matter what directory I launch it in.

Comment: What's the value of `sys.argv[0]` in both cases? I'll bet they're different.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was incomplete. Try `os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another os.pardir for this to work, since the first one just jumps from the file to the same folder (which doesn't happen in the interperted because you're already inside the folder):

```
topdir = os.path.normpath ( os.path.join (os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]),   
                    os.pardir, os.pardir, os.pardir) )
```

Of course, this is redundant and annoying. How about this:

```
dirs = [ os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]) ] + [os.pardir] * 3
topdir = reduce(lambda x, y: os.path.join(x, y), dirs)
```

it's easier to change according to level of nested file (just change the magic number 3 or even make it dynamic).